# How to enable push notification in Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode11

I'm trying to enable push notification in Xcode 11.0 . I have added push notifications form + capability but enable or disable button is not there.

[image: screenshot of capabilities]

Comment: were you able to figure out the problem? I am facing the same issue

Comment: just found it , you need to add push notification in capabilities from + capability. By default it is enabled and if you want to disable it then just remove it form capabilities.

Answer (score 16):

For Xcode v11.2.1 at least the button to add capabilities is in the upper left corner.
Once you add a new capabilitiy it's enabled by default. To disable, you delete the capability. See Screenshot for a little more detail.
[Capability SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEXax.png)

Comment: After struggling a lot with push notifications not arriving and neither official documentation of several apps and examples says how to add the push notification capability this did the trick. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 9):

In Xcode 11 or above update some many things. For push notification enable and disable check the attack screen short.

On top Upper corner click on capability:

[image: On top Upper corner click on capability]

push notification when you click then automatically enable:

[image: The other pic show push notification when you click then automatically enable]

if you want disable then -> *TARGETS* -> *Signing & Capabilities* and scroll down click on cross for disable

Comment: Strange but push notification is not listed for me.

Answer (score 7):

> Strange but push notification is not listed for me. - Tejas K

Me too! This is **another** Xcode bug I have found. You can workaround it by unchecking and rechecking the `Automatically manage signing box`, you should see a longer list of capabilities now:

[image: Image of capabilities pop up]

Comment: Push Notification is Not Showing Me Till Now. I have applied your solution multiple times. Kindly help with this.

Answer (score 3):

https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6

If you guys got trouble with App Capabilities and got missed/can't find Push Notification, there is related link that show limitation between free and paid   Apple Developer Account.

In summaries Free Account didn’t get push notification support capability. Update your Apple Dev Account! Cheerss!